# Calculating the partial sum of series within three decimal places

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I need help with my homework to calculate the partial sum of the following series that is within 0.001 of the value of the series.

- Series1: [image: Series1]
- Series2: [image: Series2]

I tried the following code for a similar series 1/n^3 and it worked fine by giving me n=71:

```
Solve[Abs[Integrate[1/n^3, n]] == .0001, n]

Limit[N[Sum[1/i^3, {i, 71, n}]], n -> Infinity]
```

But when I tried the same setup with series1 and series2, it wouldn't work. I asked a few people and they gave me hints that I had to use `FindRoot` for series1 and a while loop for series2, however, it also failed when I tried that. Any sort of help would be appreciated as I've been trying to solve these problems for numerous hours and got almost nowhere.

Comment: do you know you can directly use Infinity as a sum limit? Your last example for instance can be done as `Sum[1/i^3, {i, 71, Infinity}] // N`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first sum, you could use the fact that the remainder `\sum_{n=M}^\inf \log n/n^2` is bounded from above by `\int_{M-1}^\inf \log n/n^2 \text{d}n = \frac{1+\log(M-1)}{M-1}`. Now, since this expression as a function of `M` is monotonically decreasing (since all terms of the original sum are positive), you can find for which value it falls below the required threshold as:

```
M = Ceiling[(x /. FindRoot[(1 + Log[x-1])/(x-1) == 0.001, {x, 10}])]
10235

N[Sum[Log[n]/n^2, {n, 1, \[Infinity]}]] - N[Sum[Log[n]/n^2, {n, 1, M}]]
0.000999816
```

The second sum is a bit easier since we know that the exact result is `-Log[2]`, thus one can check directly with a `While` loop how many terms are necessary:

```
s = 0; j = 0; While[Abs[-Log[2.] - s] > 0.001, j += 1; s += (-1)^j/j;]; j
500

N[Abs[-Log[2] - Sum[(-1)^n/n, {n, 1, j}]]]
0.000999
```